# solc not importing from github

Tags: solc, compilation, import

In a Solidity source file I have an `import` along the lines of...

`import 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/<source>.sol';`

which works fine in Browser Solidity but `solc` (ver 0.3.6) cannot import it and returns an error along the lines of:

`Source "<source>.sol" not found: File not found.`

From [the path resolution](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#path-resolution) documentation I was of the understanding that `solc` could discover such import paths as Browser Solidity has demonstrated.

Am I missing something (perhaps the URL is wrong) or is it just not a feature yet?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html#use-in-actual-compilers), `solc` does not allow to import from github directly. You need to clone the repo and remap the directory path to be able to use them like in `browser-solidity`.